# Auto key bones with controller helpers

Tags: unity, animation, 3dsmax, rigging

I have skinned and rigged a human character with IK / FK and helper objects to control the position of the IK goals and the rotation of the bones. For example, the characters' left arm IK goal is parented to a point helper, to make it easier to select and move around and the arm IK solves accordingly.

I have the skeleton (without the helpers) set up as an avatar in Unity and I want to use this rig to create and export animations to work with the avatar.

I create animations by moving the helpers in Auto Key mode in 3DS Max, so that when the helpers move, their new transform details (pos, rot, scale) are recorded in key frames.

My questions is this: using Auto Key only records the transform of the helpers I'm moving, it does not record the bone transforms, even though they have been changed by moving the linked helpers. Is there any way to record bone positions using Auto Key with this rigging method, or do I have to select the affected bones every time a movement is made and use Set Key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer - bake the animation when exporting as fbx. This includes the movement of the bones even if they were not keyframed.

Select all bones > Export Selected, under Animation, tick Bake.